# Is there a way to change the placeholder text of a spinner in streamlit?

Tags: streamlit

I would like to change the placeholder text displayed when calling a function:

[image]

I tried using

```py
with st.spinner(text="Fetching measures"):
    measures = fetch_measures(userid, start_ts, end_ts)
```

but it just adds a new warning above with “Fetching measures”. Is there a way to just change the text “Running function_name(…)”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way as found on the [Streamlit's forum](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/is-there-a-way-to-change-the-placeholder-text-of-a-spinner/3906/3):

```py
@st.cache(show_spinner=False)
def fetch_measures():
    # do stuff
    time.sleep(10)


def main():
    with st.spinner(text="Fetching measures"):
        measures = fetch_measures()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Just add `show_spinner=False` inside the `st.cache()` decorator to remove the warning. Then, add your own warning with `with st.spinner(text="Fetching measures")`.